# How do I convert to the type IList?

Tags: c#

I want to achieve the effects of putting in random numbers in an `IList` and it seems I am unable to think of how to get the type of the `IList`, whether an `int` or `decimal`, etc. I cannot simply cast the `Console.ReadLine()` to the type of the `IList`.

```
public void RandomizeIList<T>(IList<T> list)
{
    randomNum = new Random();
    T typeRead = 0, typeReadSeed = 0;
    String strRead = "", strReadSeed = "";
    Console.WriteLine("How many {0}s do you want to randomly generate?", list.GetType());
    T strRead = (list.GetType())Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("What's the limit of the randomly generated {0}s?", list.GetType());
    Int32.TryParse(strReadSeed, out intReadSeed);
    for (int i = 0; i < strRead; i++)
    {
        list[i] = randomNum.Next(intReadSeed);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're having difficulty because this is not a good use of generics in the first place. A generic method that takes a T should be able to take *any possible T*. String, object, giraffe, bowl of fruit, whatever.

Comment: Please note that `list[i] = randomNum.Next(intReadSeed);` is erroneous here and will crash in many cases. You should use `list.Add(randomNum.Next(intReadSeed));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntactically what you want is:

```
T strRead = (T)Console.ReadLine();
```

However, `Console.ReadLine` *only* returns a string, so this cast (and the use of generics) makes no sense.  Either you should be using a `IList<string>` (because you think `T` is a string) or you should be using `IList<int>` (because you are adding `int`s to the list).  In  any case, it's very unclear what you are trying to accomplish, since you are doing nothing with `strRead`.

**Update, per comment**:

Certainly, you can convert a string to an arbitrary type.  The framework provides some utilities for this, such as the `Convert` class:

```
T strRead = (T)(object)Convert.ChangeType(Console.ReadLine(), typeof(T));
```

This will work for simple types -- you can use `Convert` to convert a `string` to an `int`, for example.  However, it should go without saying that you can't use this class to convert any arbitrary string to any arbitrary type.  For that, you will have to consider your own type conversion framework, perhaps combining the behaviors of `Convert`, with implicit and explicit conversions, etc.  This is because it's clear that the string representation of a particular type is entirely dependent on the characteristics of that type.

Comment: I'm wanting to convert whatever the user input string is, in this case `Console.ReadLine()` to the type of data the list can handle.